# TypeError: undefined is not an object(evaluation'this.setState')

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to render one of export function to one of my component ( here is renderheaderCommentPart to SignIN component)

This is working if I put follow code which has called modal component directly inside SignIn Component, but once I packed in another component as export function, it is not working and show error message " TypeError: undefined is not an object(evaluation "this.setState")

I tried to defined the setSate but still the same error, and I do not have to use bind(this) in construct class cause this is not event DOM handler

Please help me, thank you!!

```
 export function renderheaderCommentPart(onPress, hearderLeftText, modalContent)
{
   this.setState({
       visible: true,
       swipeableModal: false
   });
   return (
        <View>
            <Header style={Styles.header}>
                  <Left>
                    <Button transparent  onPress={onPress}>
                      <Icon name='ios-arrow-back'/>
                    </Button>
                  </Left>
                  <Body>
                    <Title style={Styles.headerText}>{hearderLeftText}</Title>
                  </Body>
                  <Right>         
                    <View>
                     <Button transparent
                       onPress={() => {
                          this.setState({ visible: true });
                        }}
                     >
                      <Icon style={Styles.icon_more} name='more' />
                    </Button>
                     <Modal
                        visible={this.state.visible}
                        onTouchOutside={() => {
                                  this.setState({ visible: false });
                                }}
                        footer={
                          <ModalFooter>
                            <ModalButton
                              text="CANCEL"
                              onPress={() => {
                                      this.setState({ swipeableModal: false });
                                    }}
                            />
                            <ModalButton
                              text="OK"
                              onPress={() => {}}
                            />
                          </ModalFooter>
                        }
                      >
                        <ModalContent>
                          <Text>{modalContent}</Text>
                        </ModalContent>
                      </Modal>
                    </View>
                  </Right>
                </Header>
            </View>
     )
}
```

Expect:
in SignIN component in render part

should be show the renderheaderCommentPart function as defined in another file

Answer (score 1):

This looks like functional component which has not setState(); use callback function as a props to set state in the parent component.

setState() is asynchronous function of class base component.

or use Hooks if your project react version 16.8. and above

Or convert your component as class base

Comment: Tks @Prabhunath Yadav, I could use Hooks cause my react is 16.9, I tried to add hook like this: const [visible, swipeableModal] = useState( '' );, then onPress ={() => { visible(false)}}, but show up another error message

Comment: It may be hook concept issue
const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);      here visible is hooks state variable that data holds and setVisible is function to update hooks state variable - visible value. 

and useState(false); - false is default value